# Parsing a file to assign variables to strucuture. C++

Tags: c++, file, parsing

Here is my code, I'm genuinely interested how far off I am.

```cpp
bool characterGetCFG(char typeOverLoad, string var_name, string full_text)
{
    int pos = full_text.find(var_name) + 1;
    if (full_text.at(pos) == *"t") {
        cout << "returned " << full_text.at(pos) << "\n";
        return true;
}
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int characterGetCFG(int typeOverLoad, string var_name, string full_text)
{
    int pos = full_text.find(var_name) + var_name.length() + 1;
    cout << "returned " << full_text.at(pos) << "\n";
    return full_text.at(pos);
}

features setconfig(features featstruct)
{
    features config; //BOOL/BOOL/BOOL/BOOL/INT[2]/BOOL/INT
    ifstream file;
    file.open("config.cfg");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    string raw;
    while (file.good()) {
        file >> raw;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++) {
        switch (x) {
        case 1:
            config.var1 = characterGetCFG('t', "var1", raw);
        case 2:
            config.var2 = characterGetCFG('t', "var2", raw);
        case 3:
            config.var3 = characterGetCFG('t', "var3", raw);
        case 4:
            config.var4 = characterGetCFG('t', "var4", raw);
        case 5:
            config.var5[1] = characterGetCFG(136, "var51", raw); //min
        case 6:
            config.var6[2] = characterGetCFG(542, "var62", raw); //max
        case 7:
            config.var7 = characterGetCFG('t', "var7", raw);
        case 8:
            config.var8 = characterGetCFG('t', "var8", raw);
        case 9:
            config.var9 = characterGetCFG('t', "var9", raw);
        case 10:
            config.var10 = characterGetCFG('t', "var10", raw);
        case 11:
            config.var11 = characterGetCFG('t', "var11", raw);
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return config;
}
```

And here is my text/cfg file I am using

```
var1=false
var2=false
var3=true
var4=false
var51=2
var62=7
var7=true
var8=t
var9=true
var10=true
var11=true
```

Here is what I am getting returned when I print what I am returning to console

[image]

As you can see it does not reflect how many times I iterate through the loop, so at the end of the day I'm stumped.

Comment: Why don't you look at what's in `raw`, after your `while` loop is done. You will be surprised to find how little is there. Given what ends up in `raw`, you can't expect to be able to do much with it. Finally, the `switch` statement is not right. When `x` is 1, for example, every statement in the switch case executes. That won't work, you need `break`s there. And the last compounded error is a lack of error checking; you are completely unaware that pretty much all `find()` calls fail because of the other problems, and, thusly, you are unaware of the prior problems happening prior to that point.

Comment: When you write code, it is very important to start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then build up. It is not clear what you want this code to do, but you seem to be trying to parse a dozen lines of text before you know how to parse one.

Comment: Great inputs guys! I really appretiate it, could either of you help direct me to some documentation reguarding my misinterpertations? I'm still not understanding where exactly I'm botching this witin the code.